# Eines Tages, is it Genitive form?

Tags: noun, expression

I see stories starting with "Eines Tages,". Why is it not "Ein Tag"? Is "Eines Tages" a genitive form here? meaning "Of one day"? I am a beginner on German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eines Tages does, in fact, mean roughly "of one day," which requires the genitive (not "generative" case). And that because it is a  reference to one *particular* day. The idiomatic English expression is "once upon a time."

You would use "ein(en) Tag" to refer to a "random," or unspecified day. "Ich brauche einen Tag nach Berlin zu fahren." (I need one (random) day to drive to Berlin.)

Comment: The British have an expression "of an evening" meaning "most evenings" or "on many evenings", so it's not without precedent in English. Parts of day can be used as well, *eines Abends* - "one evening", *eines Morgens* - "one morning", etc. These are usually talking about past events, while *eines Tages* is mostly about some possible future event.

Answer (score 6):

**Eines Tages** is a fixed phrase meaning *some day* or *once*. It's in genitive but analyzing this further won't help you. You may ask "whose day?" and the answer would be "once". Remember it as a phrase:

> Eines Tages habe ich meine Schlüssel verloren.

*Some day I lost my keys.*

This use of *eines Tages* is typically introducing stories. *Eines Nachts* is also possible:

> Ich wachte eines Nachts auf und meine Frau war einfach weg.

*Some night I woke up and my wife was simply gone.*

---

There is another use of *eines Tages* which refers to the future instead:

> Du wirst mir eines Tages noch dafür danken.

*You will be grateful for this some day.*

It's uncommon to use *eines Nachts* that way, it would be understood as word play.

Comment: Ok but "eines Tages" literally means "of one day" not "one's day", doesn't it?

Comment: Not in this meaning. I give you an example: *"Ich habe die Arbeit **eines Tages** geschafft."* can be translated both into *"I have finished the work **of one day**.*" and "I (will) have finished the work **some day**." In speech,  stressing *eines Tages* suggests the first meaning, stressing *geschafft* the latter.

Comment: Yes that's what I understand. I'm sorry but what's the infinitiv form of geschafft? I looked it up on the web dictionary but it's not p.p. of schaffen(p.p. = geschaffen) and couldn't find from 'finish' backward.

Comment: *Schaffen* has two different past participles with four different meanings: *geschaffen haben* (to have created), *geschaffen sein* (to be meant), *geschafft haben* (to have finished) and *geschafft sein* (to be exhausted).

Comment: that's a difficult word and I will remember. Thanks!